# is dispose need for using()?

Tags: methods, dispose, streamreader, using

```
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader((Stream)cryptoStream))
{
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Does the using method dispose automatically for streamReader?

Or do I have to manually dispose of streamReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `using` statement will automatically call `Dispose` when the variable goes out of scope.

Basically:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader())
{
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader()
try 
{
   return streamReader.ReadToEnd(); 
}
finally 
{
   streamReader.Dispose();
}
```